# How do nominations work?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Can a person only nominate themselves?  Can community members nominate other community members?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only nominate yourself.  If you think someone else would be a good moderator, the most you can do is to encourage them to nominate themselves.

Comment: It would be nice if this was made more clear in SEs pages discussing it.

Answer (score 3):

You can only self-nominate. As noted on the recent election page:

> *NOTE*: The only way to be nominated is by nominating yourself. The way you do that is by clicking the "Nominate yourself as a Candidate" link below and then answering the questionnaire on Meta.

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/election/3